# I am trying to use user input in a bash program, but I think my code is very wrong

Tags: bash, input

I am trying to use the input of the user to set a message in the OS X login screen, but it sets the message to STRING, instead of the actual message.

In python for example to declare a string to a variable this is done by:

```
myString = str(input("Name your message")
```

My question; how to do the same in bash? My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#User sets login message
echo Please name your input

#"text" to STRING?
declare STRING variable
STRING="Hello World"

#set message
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow LoginwindowText $STRING

#last output
echo you named the message $STRING
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the "read" command.

```
echo -n "Enter your name and press [ENTER]: "
read name
echo $name
```

Reference:

> http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html

Once you have it in a variable, you know what to do.